# How to update Fabric & Crashlytics?

Tags: ios, xcode7, crashlytics, twitter-fabric, bitcode

I installed Fabric and crashlytics framework using fabric app and not cocoapods. 
I needed to update it to comply with this error and for the future.

> /Crashlytics.framework/Crashlytics(CrashlyticsPlaceholderStatic.o)'
>   does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled
>   (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the
>   vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture arm64

and I've [read](https://twittercommunity.com/t/crashlytics-does-not-contain-bitcode-you-must-rebuild-it-with-bitcode-enabled/52817) that the update will fix the issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Mike from Crashlytics and Fabric here.

If you updated to Crashlytics 3.3.1 and Fabric 1.5.1, then those frameworks support Bitcode enabled app. Release notes [here.](https://docs.fabric.io/ios/changelog.html#changelog)

Comment: Hi Mike, I've read that. How do I update my current crashlytics and fabric without using cocoapods? I thought I could just use the fabric app. Thanks!

Comment: If you open up Fabric.app, then click on the kit-selector in the top-right corner, there should be an option to update the frameworks. If you don't see that, try restarting Fabric.app.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain how to update.  As for @MikeBonnell's comment, I tried updating the kits via the Kits button on the right of the upper "tab bar", but that approach seems to require being able to build the app.

Comment: Yes, updates through Fabric.app happen on build. You can also use CocoaPods.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Build Settings(target's), find the

> 'Enable Bitcode' key under 'Build options'

Set it's value to NO.

REASON: iOS9 has this option from Xcode 7, By default it is set as YES(I guess). Since, third party frameworks like Crashlytics doesn't updated for bitcode enabled mode. So, set it NO.

Comment: Right now, bitcode apps are optional, but history has shown Apple turns optional things into requirements (like 64 bit support). This usually takes a few years, so third party developers (like Parse) have time to update. ~Jeffery Thomas

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other solutions:

Fabric was not recognizing that my project had an outdated Crashlytics version. It listed my "Installed" version as 3.3.4 when infact it was v3.0.x.

I clicked "Install" on Crashlytics and was prompted to rebuild project. But the project rebuild was failing due to the Bitcode being enabled and my Crashlytics.framework version being outdated.

I disabled Bitcode, and successfully built, at which point Fabric updated my Crashlytics. THereafter, I was able to turn Bitcode back on and continue to build successfully with Crashlytics v3.3.4

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem this way:

1. Build settings -> Build Options -> Enable Bit = NO
2. Build app
3. Fabric notifies that I have to update Crashlytics framework, so I have built app to update framework
4. Build settings -> Build Options -> Enable Bit = YES

And everything works fine now.